# cannot convert value of type 'OSLogMessage' to expected dictionary key type 'AnyHashable'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting this error when I run. It builds successfully and everything works perfect in the simulator, but this particular screen won't build in the preview and it's giving this error. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be great

```
Compiling failed: cannot convert value of type 'OSLogMessage' to expected dictionary key type 'AnyHashable'

error: cannot convert value of type 'OSLogMessage' to expected dictionary key type 'AnyHashable'
        db.collection(__designTimeString("#7729.[3].[7].[1].modifier[0].arg[0].value", fallback: "movies")).document("\(self.movie.id)").updateData([__designTimeString("#7729.[3].[7].[1].modifier[2].arg[0].value.[0].key", fallback: "items"): FieldValue.arrayUnion(self.selections)])
```

Code it seems to be referencing

```
func addItems() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("movies").document("\(self.movie.id)").updateData(["items": FieldValue.arrayUnion(self.selections)])
    }
```

**UPDATED WITH MORE CODE**

```
@State var selections: [String] = []
```

```
VStack {
ForEach(viewModel.items.indices, id: \.self) { i in
          HStack {
            Text(viewModel.items[i].name)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.selections = [viewModel.items[i].name]
                self.addItems()
                }) {
                    Text("Add")
                    }
                }
          }
   }
   .onAppear() { self.viewModel.fetchData() }
```

Comment: The error is clear; what your attempting to write to Firebase is not valid. Please do some troubleshooting to determine what isn't valid here `FieldValue.arrayUnion(self.selections)]`. Probably a good idea to print that out to console to inspect what it contains. Since that data wasn't included in the question it would be impossible for us to pinpoint the issue. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My apologies for not putting enough info in the original question. I've updated it with more relevant code. I've tried printing "self.selections" on the button action and its all working properly, the item is being written to the Firestore db in the exact way that I was intending, the only problem is getting the preview in Xcode, and having this error shown. It still builds fine in simulator and on device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this one for anyone who comes across this. Code below fixed all problems

```
@State var selection = ""
```

```
VStack {
ForEach(viewModel.items.indices, id: \.self) { i in
          HStack {
            Text(viewModel.items[i].name)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.selection = viewModel.items[i].name
                self.addItems()
                }) {
                    Text("Add")
                    }
                }
          }
   }
   .onAppear() { self.viewModel.fetchData() }
```

```
func addItems() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("movies").document("\(self.movie.id)").updateData([AnyHashable("items"): FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(self.selection)"])])
    }
```