# cannot convert value of type 'OSLogMessage' to expected dictionary key type 'AnyHashable'when implementing youtubeioshelper in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, youtube-api

I searched a quite a long time for the answer but didn't get much helpful advice,
here is my code:

```
struct testdate: View {
    
    var body: some View {
     YTWrapper(videoID: "jQtP1dD6jQ0")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: center)

    }

}
struct YTWrapper : UIViewRepresentable {
    var videoID : String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> YTPlayerView {
        
        let playerView = YTPlayerView()
        playerView.load(withVideoId: videoID,playerVars: ["playInline" : 1])
        return playerView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: YTPlayerView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

I get an error info:
`Compiling failed: cannot convert value of type 'OSLogMessage' to expected dictionary key type 'AnyHashable'` , if I delete `playerVars: ["playInline" : 1]`, then it is ok but always enters a full screen when playing. What I need is to make it plays inline

Comment: Weird error. I wonder why the compiler thinks the `String` is an `OSLogMessage`? This question seems to have an answer for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261655/cannot-convert-value-of-type-oslogmessage-to-expected-dictionary-key-type-any

Answer (score 0):

I just casually add some code like this and it works,

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> YTPlayerView {
        let playvarsDic = [ "playsinline": 1]
        
        let playerView = YTPlayerView()
        playerView.load(withVideoId: videoID,playerVars: playvarsDic)
        return playerView
    }
```